# How can i enable only latest version searchable in alfresco?

Tags: search, version, alfresco

How can i make only latest version searchable in alfresco repository? E.g. if a content named abc.doc has version 1.0 & 2.0; how can i make alfresco search to find only abc.doc version 2.0 in search?

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1):

This is the default behavior. Only the latest version is indexed. Aside from proving this through a test, you can also use CMIS to query the repository's capabilities. It reports "AllVersionsSearchable" as false.

```
>>> repo.info['productName']
u'Alfresco Repository (contentUrl=|mimetype=|size=0|encoding=|locale=en_US_|id=120)'
>>> repo.info['productVersion']
u'4.2.0 (4576)'
>>> repo.getCapabilities()['AllVersionsSearchable']
False
```